# How to Programmatically Restart a Single Instance application

Tags: wpf, restart, single-instance

My WPF program uses [SingleInstance.cs](http://blogs.microsoft.co.il/blogs/arik/SingleInstance.cs.txt) to make sure that only one instance of it is running if a user tries to restart it by double clicking a short cut to it or some other mechanism.  However, there is a circumstance in my program where it needs to restart itself.  Here's the code I use to perform the restart:

```
App.Current.Exit += delegate( object s, ExitEventArgs args ) {
    if ( !string.IsNullOrEmpty( App.ResourceAssembly.Location ) ) {
        Process.Start( App.ResourceAssembly.Location );
    }
};

// Shut down this application.
App.Current.Shutdown();
```

This works most of the time, but the problem is it doesn't always work.  My guess is that on some systems, the first instance and the `RemoteService` it creates haven't terminated yet and this causes the process started by the call to `Process.Start( App.ResourceAssembly.Location );` to terminate.

Here's the Main method in my app.xaml.cs:

```
[STAThread]
public static void Main() {
    bool isFirstInstance = false;

    for ( int i = 1; i <= MAXTRIES; i++ ) {
        try {
            isFirstInstance = SingleInstance<App>.InitializeAsFirstInstance( Unique );
            break;

        } catch ( RemotingException ) {
            break;

        } catch ( Exception ) {
            if ( i == MAXTRIES )
                return;
        }
    }    

    if ( isFirstInstance ) {
        SplashScreen splashScreen = new SplashScreen( "splashmph900.png" );
        splashScreen.Show( true );

        var application = new App();
        application.InitializeComponent();
        application.Run();

        SingleInstance<App>.Cleanup();
    }
}
```

What's the right way to get this code to allow a new instance to start if it's being restarted programmatically?  Should I add a `bool` flag `Restarting` and wait in the `for` loop for the call to `SingleInstance<App>.InitializeAsFirstInstance` to return true?  Or is there a better way?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

One thing to do would be that when you call Process.Start, pass an argument to the executable telling it that it is an "internal restart" situation. Then the process can handle that by waiting for a longer period of time for the process to exit. You could even tell it the ProcessID or something so it knows what to watch for.

Comment: I'd already tried something like that (the string "Restart" has to be passed), and it seems to work, but I like passing the process ID.  That way a user can't spoof a restart.